# Why do our queries get stuck on the state "Writing to net" in MySql?

Tags: mysql

We have a lot of queries

```
select * from tbl_message
```

that get stuck on the state "Writing to net". The table has 98k rows.

The  thing is... we aren't even executing any query like that from our application, so I guess the question is:

- What might be generating the query?
- ...and why does it get stuck on the state *"writing to net"*

I feel stupid asking this question, but I'm 99,99% sure that our application is not executing a query like that to our database... we are however executing a couple of querys to that table using WHERE statement:

```
 SELECT Count(*) as StrCount FROM tbl_message WHERE m_to=1960412 AND m_restid=948

 SELECT Count(m_id) AS NrUnreadMail FROM tbl_message WHERE m_to=2019422 AND m_restid=440 AND m_read=1

 SELECT * FROM tbl_message WHERE m_to=2036390 AND m_restid=994 ORDER BY m_id DESC
```

I have searched our  application several times for `select * from tbl_message` but haven't found anything... But still our query-log on our mysql server is full of `Select * from tbl_message` queries

Comment: In my case this occurred because there was a daily cron task to dump the production database to a (locally mounted) networked filesystem backed by a third-party could storage provider.  The cloud provider went away at some point, which caused the `mysqldump` process to get stuck waiting for the network filesystem to accept its data, which was literally never going to happen.  Massive disruption ensued.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since applications don't magically generate queries as they like, I think that it's rather likely that there's a misstake somewhere in your application that's causing this. Here's a few suggestions that you can use to track it down. I'm guessing that your using PHP, since your using MySQL, so I'll use that for my examples.

Try adding comments in front of all your queries in the application, like this:

```
$sqlSelect  = "/* file.php, class::method() */";
$sqlSelect .= "SELECT * FROM foo ";
$sqlSelect .= "WHERE criteria";
```

The comment will show up in your query log. If you're using some kind database api wrapper, you could potentially add these messages automatically:

```
function query($sql)
{
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    // The function that executed the query
    $prev = $backtrace[1];
    $newSql = sprintf("/* %s */ ", $prev["function"]);
    $newSql .= $sql;

    mysql_query($newSql) or handle_error();
}
```

In case you're not using a wrapper, but rather executing the queries directly, you could use the runkit extension and the function [runkit_function_rename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-rename.php) to rename mysql_query (or whatever you're using) and intercept the queries.

Comment: Thanks, I like the approach of adding comments to all the queries. Actually I'm using vbscript/asp classic.

Comment: Okay. The principle still holds, but you'll have to work out how to utilize it yourself then. :)

Comment: Actually you made my day. Just to test this out I added a dummy comment before all sql statements: /*testing*/. For some reason this made the performance on all mysql calls from our vbscript/asp site much faster AND we also don't recieve select * from tbl_message anymore. I have no idea why... :-)

Comment: Glad to be of service. Always a bit scary when a problem just disappears for no reason, though.

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug#Heisenbug : "A heisenbug (named after the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle) is a computer bug that disappears or alters its characteristics when an attempt is made to study it." ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two data retrieval modes for mysql. With the c api you either call [mysql_store_result()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-store-result.html) or [mysql_use_result()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-use-result.html).
mysql_store_result() returns when all result data is transferred from the MySQL server to your process' memory, i.e. no data has to be transferred for further calls to mysql_fetch_row().

However, by using mysql_use_result() each record has to be fetched individually if and *when* mysql_fetch_row() is called. If your application does some computing that takes longer than the time period specified in [net_write_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_read_timeout) between two calls to mysql_fetch_row() the MySQL server considers your connection to be timed out.

Comment: The C function mysql_use_result() is used by the PHP function mysql_unbuffered_query(). Thus the error could be generated in the manner you're describing using PHP (even though I'm still not sure that's what the OP is using :). Good point.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily enable the query log by putting

```
log=
```

into your my.cnf file, restart mysql and watch the query log for those mystery queries (you don't have to give the log a name, it'll assume one from the host value).