# DBForge hangs server with thousand of records

Tags: mysql, devart, dbforge

First,

- I have a table with 1500 records
- I'm using MySQL 5.0.54.
- I'm using dbForge for MySQL 5.0.97

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS s_users(
  user_id MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL,
  employee_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  surname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  firstname VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  phone VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  organization_eng VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  organization_fra VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  unit_id SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  unit_name_eng VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  unit_name_fra VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  status ENUM('active', 'inactive') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'inactive',
  udate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
ENGINE = MYISAM
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 131
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The statement:

```
select * from s_users;
```

Here are the steps taken to reproduce:

1. Run the query: **select * from s_users;**
2. Do not scroll to the end of the recordset, it indicates 1 of 302+
3. In another window, run the query **show full processlist;**
4. In the state, it will show **Writing to net**
5. Until I scroll to the end of the recordset of my initial SQL statement, or close the tab where the statement is run, the query will keep on taking up CPU (time column keeps increasing) and block the rest of the statements.

I figure I'm missing a setting somewhere in dbForge?

**Update #1**

This was brought to my attention:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/802686/503246

Maybe DBForge is using a specific C API call that results in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that you have to switch to Paginal Mode. By default it's in fetching mode, which keeps the connection open until you navigate to the end of the recordset.

To change to Paginal Mode:

1. Select 'Tools -> Options' from the main menu. The 'Options' window opens.
2. Navigate to the 'Data Editor -> General' branch.
3. Select the 'Use paginal mode by default' option and set 'Initial page size'.